# In ASP.NET Core authorization, how do I check permissions for either app or user access tokens on the same controller action?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

The OAuth implementation on Microsoft's Identity Platform uses scopes for delegated permissions and roles for application permissions. I'm writing a protected web API that supports both types of access tokens.

For scope verification, I can apply `[Authorize(Policy = "HasTheScope")]` to my controller action with the following policy definition:

```
options.AddPolicy("HasTheScope", policy => policy.RequireClaim("scp", "TheScope"));
```

For role verification, I can apply `[Authorize(Policy = "HasTheRole")]` with the following policy definition:

```
options.AddPolicy("HasTheRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("TheRole"));
```

With multiple `[Authorize]` attributes, all of them must be fulfilled, so it's not possible to simply apply both policies to the action.

What's the best practice approach to allow access to my controller action for both app requests (tokens created with the client credentials flow) and requests on a user's behalf (tokens created with the authorization code flow)?

Answer (score 0):

Feels like logically you need to look at incoming tokens and do different things for the client credentials flow, where there will be no subject claim.

So an 'or' condition is needed and if you want to use policies define a custom one - have a look at the RequireAssertion syntax - this [Curity guides article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/dotnet-api/) has some examples:

```cs
options.AddPolicy("lowRisk", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(claim => 
                claim.Type == "risk" && Int32.Parse(claim.Value) < 50
            )
        )
    );
```